# How do I insert an object data array into a database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to insert data from an array into a database table in the submit() function where the sql syntax is at. I want to insert the data then redirect to another page after successful. I don't know how to do this with ajax.

I tried to make ajax syntax but I don't know if i'm passing the data correctly for obj.name and obj.books corresponding to their own values in the array.

example:
[{"name":"book1","books":["thisBook1.1","thisBook1.2"]},{"name":"book2","books":["thisBook2.1","thisBook2.2","thisBook2.3"]}]

```
function submit(){
    var arr = [];
    for(i = 1; i <= authors; i++){
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = $("#author" + i).val();
        obj.books = [];
        $(".auth" + i).each(function(){
            var data = $(this).val();
            obj.books.push(data);
        });
        //sql = ("INSERT INTO table (author, book) VALUES ('obj.name', 'obj.books')");
        //mysqli_query(sql);
        arr.push(obj);
    }

    $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
/////////////////////////////////
//I tried this:
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {arr: arr},
   url: "next.php",
   success: function(){

   }
});
/////////////////////////////////
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- #main {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
    <div class="my-form">
      <form action"next.php" method="post">
          <button onclick="addAuthor()">Add Author</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div id="addAuth"></div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var authors = 0;

    function addAuthor() {
      authors++;
      var str = '<br/>' + '<div id="auth' + authors + '">' + '<input type="text" name="author" id="author' + authors + '" placeholder="Author Name:"/>' + '<br/>' + '<button onclick="addMore(\'auth' + authors + '\')" >Add Book</button>' + '</div>';
      $("#addAuth").append(str);
    }

    var count = 0;

    function addMore(id) {
      count++;
      var str = '<div id="bookDiv' + count + '">' + '<input class="' + id + '" type="text" name="book' + id + '" placeholder="Book Name"/>' + '<span onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv' + count + '\')" style="font-size: 20px; background-color: red; cursor:pointer; margin-left:1%;">Remove</span>' + '</div>';
      $("#" + id).append(str);
    }

    function removeDiv(id) {
      //var val = confirm("Are you sure ..?");
      //if(val){
      $("#" + id).slideUp(function() {
        $("#" + id).remove();
      });
      //}
    }

    function submit() {
      var arr = [];
      for (i = 1; i <= authors; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = $("#author" + i).val();
        obj.books = [];
        $(".auth" + i).each(function() {
          var data = $(this).val();
          obj.books.push(data);
        });
        //                            sql = ("INSERT INTO table (author, book) VALUES ('obj.name', 'obj.books')");
        //                            mysqli_query(sql);
        arr.push(obj);
      }

      $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you having issues with getting the data to PHP? Can you show what is in `next.php`

Comment: there is nothing in next.php tha is why i added `sql = ("INSERT INTO table (author, book) VALUES ('obj.name', 'obj.books')");
//mysqli_query(sql);` in the submit function syntax

Answer (score 2):

Send your array to server ,stringify array before sending it to server so in server you can decode json and recover your array, and then insert received data to database
JS

```
function submit(){
    var arr = [];
    for(i = 1; i <= authors; i++){
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = $("#author" + i).val();
        obj.books = [];
        $(".auth" + i).each(function(){
            var data = $(this).val();
            obj.books.push(data);
        });

        //sql = ("INSERT INTO table (author, book) VALUES ('obj.name', 'obj.books')");
        //mysqli_query(sql);
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    sendToServer(arr)
    $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
function sendToServer(data) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {arr: JSON.stringify(data)},
      url: "next.php",
      success: function(){

      }
   });
}
```

PHP (next.php)

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['arr']));
foreach($data as $item){
   echo $d;
   // insert to db
}
```

Comment: How do I prevent it from sending me directly to next.php after pressing a button

Comment: @learningbyexample add class to your button and remove `onclick` attribute,  `<button class="submit-btn"></button>` this do like this `$(".submit-btn").click(function(event) {  event .preventDefault(); /** cal your submit function **/ submit(); });`

Comment: `onclick="addMore(\'auth' + authors + '\')"` and `onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv' + count + '\')"`  are passing data to the function if I make it class="addMore" and class="removeDiv" how will I pass the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Please Keep the following in mind

Javascript/JQuery is client side and hence cannot access the database which is on the server.

You can Send data via AJAX to next.php and then use this data to insert into your database.

To improve debugging, use the following code to ensure the correct data is being delivered in next.php

```
   var_dump($_POST);
```

Your SQL statements must be executed in next.php using the data passed by $_POST (since your "type" of AJAX request is post).